# AngularJS UI-Router nested state view in table row (inline edit)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Working on an AngularJS + UI-Router project. Got a task with these (simplified here) requirements:

- display a list of items in a table with `Edit` button at the end of the table row
- clicking `Edit` button should turn a table row into item edit form (inline edit)
- Item list and item edit views should be accessible via url.

So I have defined my states:

```
// app.js
 $stateProvider
      .state("list", {
        url: "/",
        component: "listComponent"
      })
      .state("list.edit", {
        url: "/{id}/edit",
        component: "editComponent"
      });
  }
```

`ListComponent` template looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- Hide this row when NOT in edit mode -->
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in $ctrl.items" ng-if="$ctrl.editIndex !== $index">
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.onEditClick($index, item.id)">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Show this row when in edit mode -->
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="$ctrl.editIndex === $index">
      <td colspan="3">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And main parts from `ListComponent` itself:

```
function ListController($state) {
    this.editIndex = null;

    this.items = [
      { id: 1, name: "Y-Solowarm" },
      // ...
      { id: 10, name: "Keylex" }
    ];

    this.onEditClick = function(index, id) {
      this.editIndex = index;
      $state.go("list.edit", { id: id });
    };
  }
```

### Problem:

When I was working on `EditComponent` I noticed that it initiates http requests **twice**. After a couple of hours later I came up with such `EditComponent` that showed what actually was happening:

```
function EditController() {
    // random number per component instance  
    this.controllerId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); 

    this.$onInit = function() {
      console.log("INIT:", this.controllerId);
    };

    this.$onDestroy = function() {
      console.log("DESTROY:", this.controllerId);
    };
  }
```

Console showed this output:

```
DESTROY: 98 
INIT: 80
DESTROY: 80
INIT: 9
```

When clicking `Edit` for a second time this output shows that

- `EditComponent#98` is destroyed as we navigate away from it (expected)
- `EditComponent#80` is created and immediately destroyed (**unexpected**)
- `EditComponent#9` is created as we are now 'editing' new item (expected)

This just shows me that many `<ui-view>`s together with `ng-if`s does not play very nice but I have no idea how to fix that.

One thing that I have tried was I created one `<ui-view>` in `ListComponent` and was moving it around on ui-router state change by means of pure javascript. But that did not work as I soon started getting errors from ui-router's framework that were related to missing HTML node.

### Question:

What am I doing wrong here? I think that angular's digest cycle (and related DOM changes) end later than ui-router starts transitions and related component creation and destruction and that might be a reason of `EditComponent#80` being created and quickly destroyed. But I have no idea how to fix that.

Here is a codepen showing what is happening:
https://codepen.io/ramunsk/project/editor/AYyYqd
(don't forget to open developer console to see what's happening)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you're switching from index 2 to index 3.  I think this might be what is happening:

The ui-view at index 2 is currently active.  In the click handler you call state.go and the ui-view at index 2 briefly receives the updated state parameter `id: 3`.  Then it is destroyed when the ng-if takes effect and the ui-view at index 3 is created.

Change your code so it destroys the ui-view at index 2 *first*.  Add a timeout so it calls state.go shows the second ui-view in *the next digest cycle*.

```
this.onEditClick = function(index, id) {
  this.editIndex = null;
  $timeout(() => {
    this.editIndex = index;
    $state.go("list.edit", { id: id });
  });
};
```

https://codepen.io/christopherthielen/project/editor/ZyNpmv